# Define Unique Association between two fields of a table in Sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, associations, unique

I know there are lots of questions like that here, but that's not really typical one i'm asking. 
I got a table like that :

```
CREATE TABLE example (
   field1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
   field2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
   field3 TEXT,
   PRIMARY KEY(field1,field2)
   FOREIGN KEY(field2) REFERENCES example2(field2)
);
```

What I want to forbid is multiple field1 for one field3 but keeping allowed values with same field1 and field3 but different field2. 
In fact, i want a unique field1 available for each field3 but multiple field3 for each field1 if field2 are different.

To help you to understand what i mean, i give u some examples :

```
INSERT INTO example VALUES(1,1,"apple");
INSERT INTO example VALUES(1,2,"apple"); allowed
INSERT INTO example VALUES(2,1,"apple"); forbidden
INSERT INTO example VALUES(2,3,"apple"); forbidden
```

P.S. : PRIMARY_KEY(field1,field2,field3) and UNIQUE(field1,field3) are not answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your association cannot be enforced with either some `PRIMARY KEY`/`UNIQUE` or some `CHECK` constraint (because SQLite [does not allow](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst) subqueries in `CHECK` expressions).

Your problem is that this table is not properly [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), i.e., it is not in [second normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).
The `field3` column probably should be moved to a separate table (but this is hard to say without knowing the meaning of those values).